# Is there something like a thesaurus for archaic german words?

Tags: meaning, resource

For writing purposes I am looking for a collection of archaic german words, or words that have gone out of fashion.

I've had some success [with the german text archives](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/doku/clarin_kupro_liste?g=19) or this [simple lexikon](https://ewnor.de/lexikon/index.php). I am using the classical thesaurus as well, but I am only looking for older versions of words right now.

Do you know of any book / website etc. which would allow me to lookup archaic versions of german words?

My current plan if everything else fails is to keep on reading Nietzsche and Schiller etc. as a source of those words, but a concentrated source would be so much more effective!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two approaches using [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/) (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache).

If you are looking for old/archaic versions of todays words you can type in the modern word and dwds will give you a few alternatives in the thesarus section at the end of the page. The words labeled as "veraltet" are what you are looking for.

e.g.

> [(sich) unterhalten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/unterhalten) -> [konversieren](https://www.dwds.de/wb/konversieren)

---

If you are looking for any archaic words, you can combine a google search with dwds.

Search for

> site:dwds.de "veraltet"

and you will get tons of old words. Unordered ... but well :)

Comment: Works with the Duden as well: _site:duden.de "veraltend"_ / _site:duden.de "veraltet"_

Comment: You can combine this search with other terms as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since I have some understanding of the German language I think that this might be of interest

https://www.kunst-worte.de/archaismen/

Comment: A lot of these words aren't common but not uncommon either. For example *verplappern* is used sometimes, and *Knilch* is a new youth word.

Comment: *Knilch* according to "Kluge Etymologisches Wörterbuch 1999" is "< 20. Jh." *Knilch* was already old when I was young ;)

Comment: Still, archaic words may be reintegrated in the language and this lose their archaic status

Comment: But Rolf Zuckowski dug out *Knilch* for his notoric *Weihnachtsbäckerei* song, and the millions of people tortured with that song before Christmas couldn't resist using it again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced, that *archaic* is the most appropriate word when referring to 19th century.

I would have suggested authentic period references, as [Brockhaus 1894](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/), but I suspect that what you are after is  a mapping

> New term -> old term

which those won't provide.

Comment: Well it's certainly worth a shot, as there is a search option aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might find old words here:

- https://www.ommawoerter.de/
- https://sternenvogelreisen.de/schoene-woerter-jetzt-auch-als-buch/ (als eBook 5 Euro)
  https://www.achgut.com/artikel/unvollstaendige_liste_ausgestorbener_bzw._kaum_noch_benutzter_woerter_begri
- http://zeitzeugen.bplaced.net/vergessenebegriffe/index.html
- http://www.detlef-guertler.de/Rote-Liste.htm
- http://www.oberlehrer.org/vwg.html
- Bodo Mrozek: Lexikon bedrohter Wörter (1 + 2); gibt's gebraucht für wenig Geld
- https://ewnor.de/lexikon/index.php
- https://www.openthesaurus.de/tag/list?tag=veraltet
- https://www.openthesaurus.de/tag/list?tag=veraltend
- https://www.openthesaurus.de/tag/list?tag=historisch
- Matthias Heine, Verbrannte Wörter (Nazi words like '*entartet*', '*asozial*', '*Bombenwetter*')

and last but really not least (!)

> https://ediss.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/11858/00-1735-0000-0006-AEE5-2/jang.pdf?sequence=1,
>   pages 37 - 145

and many others.

I think the last one is the best to start with. It contains 2000 '*old words*' (called "veraltet" in DUW) and it provides a rough rendering into standard German.

None of the other listings is '*bilingual*' (old <-> new), nor exhaustive, nor consistent, nor based on substantially defined criteria. They are a bit like 'whatever one can stumble upon and what he doesn't know from nowadays German'.

The best resource for older and very old (Early) Modern High German ist the Brothers' Grimm dictionary:

- http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB

Here you'll find an infinite number of words that no one knows today, including their syntactic 'behavior' and an enormous number of quotations across the centuries. But of course it's just for looking up, not for reading all 34.824 pages.

Don't forget that even the most common words in current German had a different meaning and syntax in bygone times.